# Android ADT Plugin for Eclipse not working after upgrading to ver 10.0

Tags: android, eclipse

After upgrading to the newest version of the Eclipse ADT - 10.0. My projects are behaving funnily. The app runs, but when I try to open an activity (on the phone), some other activity gets opened. I then tried to create a new Android Project. I'm not able to because the list of targets (the android versions) are missing and am not able to choose 2.2 or any other version.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem. Had to change the version of Java from 1.4 to 1.6. Upgrading to ADT 10 had changed my version number! Wasted half a day on this!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
1)Open Help Menu in eclipse
2)Install New Software.
3)Click on Add
4)set Name for ADT and add this link "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" in Location. 
5)Ok
6)Select All
7)finish
```

follow this [link...](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, it says all software is already installed and does not do anything.